Hosting the Birt Viewer, But it is defaulting to 127.0.0.1
In Birt Application I have created one rptdesign file, from eclipse i ran (Run->View report->In Web Viewer), report opened using below URL.
http://127.0.0.1:54756/viewer/frameset?__report=D%3A%5Cbirt%5Cworkspace%5Cdrill_down_test.rptdesign
Above URL Im trying to use from different system by Creating DNS and making it Public.
DNS Name: birtviewer.crest-erp.com
Now the URL becomes.
https://birtviewer.crest-erp.com/viewer/frameset?__report=D%3A%5Cbirt%5Cworkspace%5Cdrill_down_test.rptdesign
Above URL I'm trying to access from different system. Contents are not loading.
Opening like below Screenshot
enter image description here
When i inspect and saw got to know that it is still considering localhost(127.0.0.1)
http://127.0.0.1:54756/viewer/webcontent/birt
enter image description here
Please help me in resolve this issue.
I tried checking the birt file structure where I can configure, Didnt fine any clue.
Using mentioned birt version
BIRT Report Designer RCP   4.8.0.v201806261756 org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.rcp
Java 1.8
I tried downloading Birt Runtime folder and followed below steps.
enter image description here
Got 404 Page not found
enter image description here
